# Odoo website: Getting Administrator if no user is logged in

Tags: odoo, odoo-10

Here is my problem [image] 
I am getting **Administrator** on the place of *Sign in* which is on top right corner of the page.

I am also getting this message in the console of browser multiple time.

```
web.assets_common.js:3028 Server application error 
{
  "message": "Odoo Session Expired",
  "code": 100,
  "data": {
    "debug": "Traceback (most recent call last):\n  File \"/var/www/html/OCB-10.0/odoo/http.py\", line 641, in _handle_exception\n    return super(JsonRequest, self)._handle_exception(exception)\n  File \"/var/www/html/OCB-10.0/odoo/addons/base/ir/ir_http.py\", line 184, in _dispatch\n    auth_method = cls._authenticate(func.routing[\"auth\"])\n  File \"/var/www/html/OCB-10.0/odoo/addons/base/ir/ir_http.py\", line 112, in _authenticate\n    getattr(cls, \"_auth_method_%s\" % auth_method)()\n  File \"/var/www/html/OCB-10.0/odoo/addons/base/ir/ir_http.py\", line 85, in _auth_method_user\n    raise http.SessionExpiredException(\"Session expired\")\nSessionExpiredException: Session expired\n",
    "exception_type": "internal_error",
    "message": "Session expired",
    "name": "odoo.http.SessionExpiredException",
    "arguments": [
      "Session expired"
    ]
  }
}
```

I think that website menu required sudo permission to create the menus and this part create the problem.

Can anyone give me some idea that why its happening.

Answer (score 0):

you may try with private window, for google chrome shortcut key Ctrl+Shift+N and also try with new Database